# Ellipse de l'épithète dans les composés constituant un terme défini

Tags: adjectifs, noms, ellipse, nom-composé

L'ellipse de l'épithète se fait couramment lorsque l'épithète résulte d'une construction libre.

- C'est une nouvelle **compagnie aérienne** ; le personnel est mal payé en raison de difficultés financières dès le début de son opération ; aucun pourparlers ne sont accordés au employés par la direction de **la compagnie**.

Cependant, lorsque le composé est le résultat d'une construction non libre, il me semble que l'ellipse n'est plus permise.

- loi martiale, vide optique, état civil, partie publique, domaine public, …

Il me semble à peu près certain que l'on ne peut pas utiliser les ellipses trouvées dans les phrases suivantes, du moins en français français ;

- Il m'a dit qu'il fallait écrire à la mairie et demander un extrait de naissance à l'état civil ; il faut vraiment que j'écrive à l'officier de **l'état** ? je ne pourrais pas lui téléphoner ?
- De la loi martiale, on en avait parlé et on était prêt à en parler encore, mais l'humeur n'y était plus, les temps  changeaient ; quel besoin en cette nouvelle période de paix assurée de parler de **la loi** ?
- …

1/ Quelqu'un pourrait-il/elle confirmer cet état de chose grammatical (ellipse impossible pour les composés non libres) comme étant la règle en français français?

Je trouve cette ellipse non voulue cependant encore aujourd'hui dans une question sur le FSE les phrases suivantes.

- Est-ce une transposition du sens au domaine public ; est-ce tributaire d'une particularité de l'Irlande et du Luxembourg dans **le domaine** ; pourquoi les guillemets ; incidemment quel serait un synonyme usuel ?

L'explication que me fournit l'auteur se borne à justifier « le domaine » comme étant une ellipse de « le domaine public ». Le domaine public n'est pas le résultat d'un composition libre, c'est un terme défini. Comme le dialecte de français dont il s'agit est le français canadien, la seconde question est celle-ci ;

2/ Si la réponse à la question précédente est dans l'affirmative, la raison de cette ellipse résulte-t-elle d'une légitimation de ce procédé d'ablation au Canada seulement ou est-ce le résultat d'une erreur dans ce dialecte aussi ?

```
……………………………………………………………………………Fin du texte de la question…………………………………………………………………………………
```

**NOTE DE JUSTIFICATION** de l'article « la » dans le premier exemple suite à une suggestion de user **radouxju** qui trouve plus exact d'utiliser « cette » (pas nécessaire à la question, peut être ignoré)

*Cas de tutoriel de journalisme _  Un instructeur parle à des élèves.*

> Prenons le cas suivant d'article à rédiger. Vous devez fournir les informations utiles sur une compagnie ; c'est une nouvelle compagnie aérienne ; le personnel est mal payé ; aucun pourparlers ne sont accordés au employés par la direction de **la/cette** compagnie.

Il me semble que les deux sont possibles dans ce cas : on discrimine parmi plusieurs compagnies au moyen de « cette » ; on détermine au moyen de « la » qu'il s'agit toujours de la compagnie introduite au début. Il me semble qu'il n'est question que du point de vue  personnel du locuteur, dont les choix sont dans ce contexte-ci sans une véritable importance.

*Cas d'un court article correspondant aux directives ci-dessus*

> Touparair n'existe que depuis quelques mois en tant que nouvelle compagnie aérienne dédiée au vols domestiques; le personnel est mal payé en raison de difficultés financières dès le début de son opération ; la nécessité de proposer des tarifs les plus compétitifs dans ce domaine où la concurrence est forte serait l'explication officieuse de cet état de chose. Aucuns pourparlers ne sont accordés aux employés par la direction de **la** compagnie, qui menace les éléments les plus virulents de ceux-ci de mise à la porte.

Il semble que dans ce cas, la discrimination soit superflue, sauf par exemple, dans un contexte social où les pourparlers sont une pratique à laquelle on est plus ou moins tenu ou du moins pas inhabituelle. En dehors d'un tel contexte c'est le démonstratif qui me semble difficilement justifiable.

Comment: je ne pense pas que ce soit une règle grammaticale. Il en va plutôt de la compréhension (ou pas) du contexte selon la spécificité du nom. Par ailleurs, même l'exemple avec "la compagnie" sonne un peu faux à mon oreille. J'aurais dit "cette compagnie" et non "la compagnie".

Comment: @radouxju Je ne veux pas trop insister sur la nomenclature, soit selon règle soit selon pratique du bien parler la question reste la même : est-ce que pour les termes cités se trouvent des cas d'ellipse ou une pratique consistante de l'ellipse ? Je ne sais pas trop quoi penser du choix entre démonstratif et article défini ; il me semble que les deux sont possibles ; je vais devoir y penser.

Comment: @radouxju J'ai ajouté des commentaires à ma réponse concernant seulement ce détail de choix entre démonstratif et article défini ; c'était trop long pour les commentaires ; n'hésitez pas à faire des remarques si vous jugez bon.

Comment: Hors sujet mais il me semble que ce devrait être *aucun**s** pourparlers ne sont...*.

Comment: Hors sujet mais il me semble que ce devrait être  : … *aucun[**s**] pourparlers ne sont* accordés au***x*** employés …

Answer (score 1):

L'ellipse est une omission tout en préservant le sens de la phrase. C'est donc un choix subjectif car il dépend du contexte et des connaissances spécifiques du public auquel on s'adresse. Je ne saurais dire si cette compréhension provient de la langue ou de la culture, les deux étant liées dans ce cas.

Pour reprendre les exemples précités, le déterminant démonstratif permet de montrer de façon précise ce dont on a parlé précédemment. Il apporte donc un supplément de précision là où l'ellipse crée une ambiguïté. Sans être nécessaire, il est donc bienvenu.

- C'est une nouvelle compagnie aérienne ; le personnel est mal payé en raison de difficultés financières dès le début de son opération ; aucun pourparlers ne sont accordés au employés par la direction de la compagnie.

Ici, "de la compagnie" n'apporte pas beaucoup d'information par rapport au contexte. J'aurais tendance soit à utiliser "de cette compagnie", soit à renforcer l'ellipse "par la direction."

- Il m'a dit qu'il fallait écrire à la mairie et demander un extrait de naissance à l'état civil ; il faut vraiment que j'écrive à l'officier de l'état ?

Ici, "état" peut prendre trop de sens différents tout en restant dans le même contexte. Je suis d'accord que dans ce cas il est difficile d'omettre le civil. Je dirais donc "l'officier d'état civil".

- De la loi martiale, on en avait parlé et on était prêt à en parler encore, mais l'humeur n'y était plus, les temps changeaient ; quel besoin en cette nouvelle période de paix assurée de parler de la loi ?

On vient de citer la loi, donc on pourrait utiliser "de cette loi" ou la remplacer par un pronom "d'en parler" sans nuire à la compréhension.

- Est-ce une transposition du sens au domaine public ; est-ce tributaire d'une particularité de l'Irlande et du Luxembourg dans le domaine ?

Dans le domaine a du sens, et pourrait vouloir dire "le domaine de la transposition du sens au domaine public". Je maintiendrais donc "domaine public", mais pas nécessairement.

Comment: En matière de langage comme en matière de légalité on est tenu bêtement à ce principe : nul n'est sensé ignorer la loi.

Comment: Votre conclusion serait donc qu'en général l'ellipse des termes composés définis dans les dictionnaires ne se fait pas ?